# Can't find Bake Option in Render Properties

Tags: interface, normals

I am using Blender 3.4.1 on a PC with an NVIDA GeForce RTX 3600. I have no *Bake* option in the *Render Properties* tab, and it doesn't matter what I select in preferences under "System": CUDA with GPU, CUDA with CPU, CUDA with both checked, Optix, or "None" -- in no case do I see the Bake Panel.  Is there a particular workspace I need to be in?  I've tried Layout, UV Editing, Rendering, and Compositing and in none of these workspaces does the Render Properties panel show "Bake". I feel as if I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. There is no *Bake* tab in *Eevee*. Are you sure you have selected *Cycles* as *Render Engine*?

Comment: Awesome, that was it.  Eevee was the default, and changing to "Cycles" brought it up. So it *was* something simple, lol.  Thank you very much!